# Changing a child element CSS contains class active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'am trying to call a function that verifies if the element contains active class whether I add a picture in my span but the problem all the span add the img tag even if i have a condition can I someone can explain to me why? and how can i fix it ?

My Div

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home</a></span><span></span></li>
                  <li><a href="reservation.html"><span>ChambresReservations</span></a><span></span></li>
                  <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact-US</span></a><span></span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

My JS

```
$(function(){
    var classExist=$(".navbar-collapse li").hasClass("active");
    if(classExist){
        $(this).find('span:nth-child(2)').append('<img src="images/site/bg-arrow-mr.png"/>')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is some problem with your script

you can get the li element which has the **class** "**active**" by

```
var elementHavingActiveClass = $(".navbar-collapse ul li.active");
```

and then set the image to the span element by

```
$(elementHavingActiveClass ).find('span:nth-child(2)').append('<img src="images/site/bg-arrow-mr.png"/>')
```

Answer (score 1):

In a single line you can achieve your target like this.

```
$(".navbar-collapse li.active").find('span:nth-child(2)').append('<img src="images/site/bg-arrow-mr.png"/>');
```

Comment: An `each` is redundant with jQuery in this (and most other) situation :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to iterate over li element. You can simply target the li element having class active using selector `li.active` and then append content inside nth span in it:

```
$(".navbar-collapse li.active").find('span:nth-child(2)').append('<img src="images/site/bg-arrow-mr.png"/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can directly use jQuery selector to find `li` with active class, see below code

```
$(function(){
    $(".navbar-collapse li.active").find('span:nth-child(2)').append('<img src="images/site/bg-arrow-mr.png"/>')
});
```

Comment: `hasClass` returns a boolean. Calling `length` on a boolean will error.

Comment: Use `$(".navbar-collapse li.active")`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan and   Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy, I corrected my answer please check